# IF statement trouble jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

```
if(jQuery('.hero .contenido .activo').next().length > 0){
    jQuery('.hero .mas').click(function(){
        jQuery('.hero .contenido').find('.activo').fadeOut('fast');
        jQuery('.hero .contenido').find('.activo').removeClass('activo').next().fadeIn('fast').addClass('activo');
    });
}
```

---

```
<div class="hero">
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="mas"></div>
        <div class="boton b1"></div>
        <div class="boton b2"></div>
        <div class="boton b3"></div>
        <div class="menos"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="contenido">
        <div class="uno activo"></div>
        <div class="dos"></div>
        <div class="tres"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The If statement is not working good, when the div class="tres" get the class "activo", just like this `<div class="tres activo"></div>` there is not a "next" div, but the IF statement still being TRUE, it never stop... I hope somebody can help

I am using jQuery.noConflict()

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Can you create it on jsbin.com?

Comment: By the way, `noConflict` should not break anything situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if statement goes inside the click function, not outside

```
jQuery('.hero .mas').bind('click', function(){
            if(jQuery('.hero .contenido .activo').next().length > 0){
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9RCQL/

Comment: Please note that the `bind` syntax is deprecated. You should now use `on`

Comment: Rodrigo Assis, u are great! now it work perfect! Thanks a lot!